# Puppeteer:for loop - syntax issue

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

What is wrong with my syntax?

it throws an error:

```
Scraping failed Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: getLogo is not defined
```

Snippet of the code:

```
      const universityAtt = await page.evaluate(() => {
            // Getting total number of universities
            let totalUniversities = document.querySelector('ul.universities-search-result').childElementCount
            for (i = 0; i < totalUniversities; i++) {
                getLogo += document.querySelectorAll('.profile_lead > .dp > img.logo-90x90')[i].src;
                universityURL += document.querySelectorAll('a.profile.adv, a.profile.basic')[i].href;
                let x = [getLogo, universityURL];
            };
            return x;
        });
```

Edit (1) When I declared the getLogo and universityURL variables,

```
        const universityAtt = await page.evaluate(() => {
            // Getting total number of universities
            let totalUniversities = document.querySelector('ul.universities-search-result').childElementCount
            for (i = 0; i < totalUniversities; i++) {
                let getLogo += document.querySelectorAll('.profile_lead > .dp > img.logo-90x90')[i].src;
                let universityURL += document.querySelectorAll('a.profile.adv, a.profile.basic')[i].href;
                let x = [getLogo, universityURL];
            };
            return x;
        });
```

I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '+='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1116:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `getLogo`, like what you did with `totalUniversities`

```js
const universityAtt = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let getLogo;
    // Getting total number of universities
    let totalUniversities = document.querySelector('ul.universities-search-result').childElementCount
    for (i = 0; i < totalUniversities; i++) {
        getLogo += document.querySelectorAll('.profile_lead > .dp > img.logo-90x90')[i].src;
        universityURL += document.querySelectorAll('a.profile.adv, a.profile.basic')[i].href;
        let x = [getLogo, universityURL];
    };
    return x;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define getLogo variable

```js
const universityAtt = await page.evaluate(() => {
            // Getting total number of universities
            
            let totalUniversities = document.querySelector('ul.universities-search-result').childElementCount
            for (i = 0; i < totalUniversities; i++) {
                let getLogo += document.querySelectorAll('.profile_lead > .dp > img.logo-90x90')[i].src;
                universityURL += document.querySelectorAll('a.profile.adv, a.profile.basic')[i].href;
                let x = [getLogo, universityURL];
            };
            return x;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

it says it right there; I see you assigning value but never declaring them with `let` `const`or`var` please do something like this first:

```
let getLogo += document.querySelectorAll('.profile_lead > .dp > img.logo-90x90')[i].src;
let universityURL += document.querySelectorAll('a.profile.adv, a.profile.basic')[i].href;
```

Comment: I get this error when I declared with "let".

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '+='

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this. Define the variable before you actually using it.

```
let testVar=0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    testVar += 3;
}
console.log(testVar);
```